# IDE for Baxter with ROS development

Tags: ros, c++, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am a beginner in ROS. I am trying to control Baxter Robot using ROS in C++ language. I am following the ROS and Baxter Tutorials to learn it. Till now, I am using gedit editor for code writing. Gedit it irritating in the sense, that I need to switch to terminal for compiling using `Catkin_Make` and switch back to Gedit incase of any error. Apart from that auto-suggestion and debugging are two big challenges, which are not available in Gedit v3.

I am looking for an IED, which has at least following support-

- Suitable for ROS + Baxter C++ code development
- Auto suggestion while writing the code (like Netbeans, Eclipse, Visual Studio etc.)
- Compile and Run Project (So that, there is no need to run `Catkin_Make` from terminal)
- Line by line debugging support (Functionality to insert breakpoint)
- Go to definition/Find all references (to see the definitions, header files etc)

Please note that I am using ROS Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit OS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221733/ide-for-baxter-with-ros-development/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2015-11-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-05-17**:
Hi, I'm also a beginner in ROS and Baxter. I'm thinking use c++ to program my Baxter robot but I only can found the python example in Baxter wiki. So may I know where can find those tutorial or like an example to use C++ to program Baxter robot? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not an IDE specific to Baxter or ROS, but a few can be made compatible, such as Eclipse and CodeBlocks. Please see the ROS Wiki page on IDEs for more details: http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2015-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2015-11-30**:
Thank you very much for providing the reference of IDE page. Well, I prefer IDE for fast and easy code development. What do you suggest to use? IDE or Gedit?

**Comment by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) on 2015-11-30**:
My personal preference is a combination of the [Terminator Ubuntu app](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/terminator/) for compiling and launching ROS nodes, and [Github's Atom IDE](https://atom.io/) for writing code.

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-05-18**:
Hi, imcmahon.
I had try to get the Atom IDE from their website. But there have two different type of file can download. one is .ded and another one is .rpm. So which one will suitable for me? by the way, I'm using ubuntu 14.04LTS 64bit.
Thank you

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-05-18**:
@Zero: You need to download deb installer file for Ubuntu OS.

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-05-18**:
Thank you so much! but where i can find the instruction for setup?

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-05-19**:
Google it bro. Check the installation section in the Github page [here](https://github.com/atom/atom#debian-linux-ubuntu)

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2016-05-19**:
Thank you, I already found it.